# Connect PGAdmin3 to Heroku PostgreSQL dedicated database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

Match the data to the boxes for me, please. Here are the (doctored) results of running `heroku config` on my shiny new dedicated database:

```
=== Config Vars for myapp
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://thinga:thingb@ec2-23-21-119-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/thingc
GEM_PATH:                    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL: postgres://thinga:thingb@ec2-23-21-119-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/thingc
HIREFIREAPP_TOKEN:           7965994a31ace96fc5f390longtoken
LANG:                        en_US.UTF-8
MEMCACHE_PASSWORD:           password
MEMCACHE_SERVERS:            mc9.ec2.northscale.net
MEMCACHE_USERNAME:           myapp%40heroku.com
PATH:                        vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:bin
PGBACKUPS_URL:               https://thing@pgbackups.heroku.com/client
RACK_ENV:                    production
RAILS_ENV:                   production
```

The fields for configuring a new server on my local PGAdmin3 are:

```
Name
Host
Port
Service
Maintenance DB
Username
Password
Group
```

What goes where?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK: everything comes from the database URL.

```
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://thinga:thingb@ec2-23-21-119-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/thingc


Name: thingc
Host: ec2-23-21-119-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Port: 5432
Service
Maintenance DB: thingc
Username: thinga
Password: thingb
Group
```